# How to implement AJAX commenting in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to 'ajaxify' commenting in WordPress using this tutorial [Ajaxify WordPress Comments](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ajaxify-wordpress-comments/)

Here is my PHP handler:

```
function ajaxify_comments( $comment_ID, $comment_status ){
    if( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) && strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) == 'xmlhttprequest' ) {
        //If AJAX Request Then
        switch( $comment_status ) {
            case '0':
                //notify moderator of unapproved comment
                wp_notify_moderator( $comment_ID );
            case '1': //Approved comment
                echo "success";
                $commentdata = &get_comment( $comment_ID, ARRAY_A );
                $post = &get_post( $commentdata['comment_post_ID'] );
                wp_notify_postauthor( $comment_ID, $commentdata['comment_type'] );
                break;
            default:
                echo "error";
        }
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'ajaxify_comments', 20, 2 );
```

And here is my script:

```
jQuery('document').ready(function($){
    var commentform=$('#commentform'); // find the comment form
    commentform.prepend('<div id="comment-status" ></div>'); // add info panel before the form to provide feedback or errors
    var statusdiv=$('#comment-status'); // define the infopanel

    commentform.submit(function(){
        //serialize and store form data in a variable
        var formdata=commentform.serialize();
        //Add a status message
        statusdiv.html('<p>Processing...</p>');
        //Extract action URL from commentform
        var formurl=commentform.attr('action');
        //Post Form with data
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: formurl,
            data: formdata,
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                statusdiv.html('<p class="ajax-error" >You might have left one of the fields blank, or be posting too quickly</p>');
                                },
            success: function(data, textStatus){
                if(data=="success")
                    statusdiv.html('<p class="ajax-success" >Thanks for your comment. We appreciate your response.</p>');
                else
                    statusdiv.html('<p class="ajax-error" >Please wait a while before posting your next comment</p>');
                    commentform.find('textarea[name=comment]').val('');
                                }
                });
                return false;
        });
});
```

Every time I post a comment, I get: "Please wait a while before posting your next comment". Hoping somebody can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Whats the value of data and textStatus when you try it? Put some `console.log(data); console.log(textStatus);` inside the success.

Comment: Just done that... The value of both console.log(data); and console.log(textStatus); is success

Comment: If so, it should go for the "Thanks for your comment. We appreciate your response." message! Do you see the comment in the database?

Comment: Yes! The comment is in the database. I agree, I should be seeing the "Thanks for your comment. We appreciate your response." message but for some reason I'm not. That's the problem... it's puzzling me

Comment: what is `formurl`? what should it be? the tutorial doesn't explain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery('document').ready(function($){
    var commentform=$('#commentform'); // find the comment form
    commentform.prepend('<div id="comment-status" ></div>'); // add info panel before the form to provide feedback or errors
    var statusdiv=$('#comment-status'); // define the infopanel

    commentform.submit(function(){
        //serialize and store form data in a variable
        var formdata=commentform.serialize();
        //Add a status message
        statusdiv.html('<p>Processing...</p>');
        //Extract action URL from commentform
        var formurl=commentform.attr('action');
        //Post Form with data
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: formurl,
            data: formdata,
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    statusdiv.html('<p class="ajax-error" >You might have left one of the fields blank, or be posting too quickly</p>');
                },
            success: function(data, textStatus){
                if(data == "success" || textStatus == "success"){
                    statusdiv.html('<p class="ajax-success" >Thanks for your comment. We appreciate your response.</p>');
                }else{
                    statusdiv.html('<p class="ajax-error" >Please wait a while before posting your next comment</p>');
                    commentform.find('textarea[name=comment]').val('');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Great! I'm now getting: "Thanks for your comment. We appreciate your response". Also, I can see comment is in the database but the problem is the comment text isn't displayed on screen until I do a manual page refresh

Comment: @gonzalo-naveira you are supposed to also give an explanation, not only copy/paste + edit the code.
This website is supposed to teach/learn from one another, is not a "who's gonna do my homework?" website.

Comment: @Dragos we've already been discussing in comments. Please see above.

Comment: @henrywright are your comments displayed automatically? Or do they need to be moderated first?

Comment: I made sure to disable moderating comments before I started testing so no, they don't require moderation. On refreshing the page the comment appears

Comment: @henrywright you should add the comment to the DOM in the success!